# Wp mail SMTP keeps showing "token revoked or expired" every week

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

I am using WP Mail SMTP for my website for sending emails to client. Every week, when I check the WP Mail SMTP in my WordPress, it is showing "Token has revoked or expired". I dont know how to solve this issue.

How to avoid this "Token has revoked or expired" issue ?

Comment: As I remember, this plugin is a premium plugin, you may use nulled version. It is better to contact their support.